# old 4.xx kernel repository at ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, compatibility

Because of compatiblity issues with the 5.xx kernel on ubuntu 20.04 at my old notebook.

Could I use to the kernel 4.xx (from 18.04 sources) with security updates inside 20.04?

The last 4.15 kernel before the ubuntu upgrade is still installed and working, but I have no updates or security fixes.

Thanks